# What Linux kernel features does os-prober require to find a Windows 8 installation?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, windows, grub2, kernel-modules

I built a new custom Linux kernel using `make localmodconfig` and after booting the new kernel, `update-grub` doesn't detect my Windows 8 installation.

My distro kernel (with tons of modules I don't need) found the Windows 8 installation and added it to the grub2 menu without any problems, so I must be missing some kernel features/modules.

What kernel features are required for the Windows 8 boot loader to be detected & added to the grub boot menu?

Answer (score 7):

`os-prober` (used by `update-grub`) requires the following kernel features to detect the Windows 8 boot loader.

- Device Drivers ->

  - Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM) (`CONFIG_MD`) ->

    - Device mapper support (`CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM`)
- File Systems ->

  - FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) support (`CONFIG_FUSE_FS`)
  - DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems ->

    - NTFS file system support (`CONFIG_NTFS_FS`)